# How to format my class? With toString, in the GUI or in other way?

Tags: c#, formatting, tostring

I have some classes in a library that are representing analysis and validation results of some files.

These classes contains enums, Lists of invalid properties, etc.

I wrote a GUI application that uses the library, and wrote some functions for writing those classes in readable form in a rich text box.

It just occured to me, that I may have to write this formatting in a ToString overriding of the class.

However, all this formatting is very long, includes inserting tabs and new lines, includes several iteration over the lists, extracting enum description etc.

So I was wondering - what is the standart for toString size and complexity? Am I suppose to write difficult formatting in the toString? Or maybe I should provide some other common interface- is there any common interface for a formatted printable output of a class? Or shall I do it in the GUI application?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget about localization. GUI texts should be in resource files. Are you sure that your program will only be used in one language? It's hard to tell how you should best do what you want to do without seeing at least some of your code. ToString seems to work best for getting really basic values like the value of an int. It's also useful for getting debug representations of your objects. If you for example do ToString on an enum you get a value that is at best camel cased and that is probably not what you want to show to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Stuff like UI formatting shouldn't be baked into any library except UI libraries.

Instead what you could do is provide a UI agnostic set of classes that can format your entities, as in, can do the complex code necessary to produce a format with the expectation of being displayed in a UI.

These could use a simple interface, something like:

```
public interface IEntityFormatter<T>
{
    string GetFormattedValue(T myEntity);
}

public class Customer
{
    public string FullName {get;set;}
}

public class CustomerFormatter : IEntityFormatter<Customer>
{
    public string GetFormattedValue(Customer myEntity)
    {
        return myEntity.FullName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `ToString` should not be very complex, otherwise, it may slow down debugging (note that it's often called automatically by the debugger). Adding your own interface also allows you to add more customization. On the other hand, if you don't need any settings for the formatting then `ToString` might be a good place to implement it.